# concat_ws убрать последний пробел

Tags: sql, psql

Надо сделать конкат нескольких колонок в psql. Делаю это через concat_ws но тогда получается пробел в конце каждой строки. rtrim не помоггает. Пример

```
 SELECT rtrim(CONCAT_WS(' ',
            '"',
            'adidas',
            'rebook',
            'nike',
            '"'
        ))
```

результат " adidas rebook nike "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CONCAT('"', 
       CONCAT_WS(' ', 'adidas', 
                      'rebook', 
                      'nike'), 
       '"')
```